# What do you think will happen when chess gets solved?

Tags: engines, solving

When some ultra strong computer discovers the perfect game of chess, will chess as a game die?

Comment: “There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable. There is another theory which states that this has already happened.” - Douglas Adams

Comment: Assuming perfect chess is a draw, I would assume players would just avoid the lines that lead to your hypothetical perfect game unless they're playing for a draw. Isn't that what happens with the Berlin and probably a lot of other lines that top players can play almost perfectly?

Comment: Also, humans play chess for fun! Just because a computer knows every eventuality, doesn't mean humans will. They will continue to enjoy the challenge of playing other humans.

Comment: At the rate progress is being made on that front (computers only know how to play 7-piece positions perfectly today,  and that happened nearly a decade ago with 8-piece positions still unsolved) none of us will be alive when that happens, and quite possibly none of our children will be either.

Comment: Even the endgame queen + pawn versus queen is hopelessly complicated without tablebases , even an engine is utterly helpless in some situations. So , as long as players really play chess (without electronic help) , chess won't die. It might however be solved within the next decades: Not that I would be happy about this, but humans always have managed impossible seeming tasks , sadly rarely in really important things.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not much. As some top players have stated, we're close to the limit of what humans can memorize to prepare for a chess game. Preparation will become slightly more refined, but that will only translate into a marginal improvement of the quality of the games.

Comment: Ancient Chess was based on scientific and logical calculations. Shad Yantra which is based on 10x10 squares cannot be solved.

Comment: @ShadYantra what are you even talking about? What's "Ancient Chess"?

Comment: Ancient Chess named "Shad Yantra" was invented by logical and keeping Millitary ranks in mind. This game is elaborated in Kautilya ArthShashtra. It is played in 10x10 board.

Answer (score 1):

Computer analysis of some parts of the start of the game might refute some openings which are at present considered sound. And possibly deem sound some openings which are at present considered dubious, by refuting their refutations.